# How to resolve this error in docker (windows 10 -- Windows 10 Education Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.720))

Tags: docker

when i excute command : docker run hello-world, but it ：

```
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem b4afe1a8be3370bfeea322594be838f489e0ee31b2f6c778632d4f66bc001280: The request is not supported.
```

> (extra info:
>   {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"b4afe1a8be3370bfeea322594be838f489e0ee31b2f6c778632d4f66bc001280","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\b4afe1a8be3370bfeea322594be838f489e0ee31b2f6c778632d4f66bc001280","Layers":[{"ID":"2ec8d054-34eb-5bf8-8669-75590ae0402b","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\66080003e563977b0112229f17e39d384c953c7091645802dd3c9e96e7d3e25c"},{"ID":"2c50ca7a-267b-5629-9fea-61de3d7064ed","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\c572c57f1168f3986ab4d7456553ba0badd86e24eb47b200947e622b59282ce8"},{"ID":"d83ba9d3-3a6d-539b-9965-ce61270585ca","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\eeb3a7fc6ebc0713f5699ee11a47bc89432abb15419ef4b440a42473ae962aea"}],"HostName":"b4afe1a8be33","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["B21A20CF-C544-4188-8E4C-2C9738FED42C"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\eeb3a7fc6ebc0713f5699ee11a47bc89432abb15419ef4b440a42473ae962aea\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).